# Determining the length of a space curve?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

What does the author integrate the magnitude of r'(t) with respect to u when the definition right above it says to integrate with respect to t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable $t$ here is not essential. It is simply a dummy variable. In this problem, $t$ is being used to refer to $r(t)$, a point on the helix, so that the variable $t$ is taken. Thus, we use $u$ instead of $t$ in the integral.

Comment: If t is non-essential, then why in (3), is r a function of t?

Comment: $t$ is simply a letter chosen from the English alphabet. We could have chosen $u$ or $v$ or $\alpha$, etc.

Comment: @user1251385 "non-essential" means we can call it $t$, $u$, $LaurelAndHardy$ or however we like.

Comment: What if you end up with a magnitude that is a function of t? Then you would have 2 different t variables which is confusing. Why would the author choose t as the dummy variable if the position vector is a function of a different variable with the same name (especially when there are 26 letters)?

Comment: Because this is a calculus course and you are expected to not get confused by a choice of variables.

Comment: I think I get it now. I was still confused why the author didn't mention it was a dummy variable in (3). But I think that it is only a dummy variable in example 9 because you are only integrating a constant so it doesn't matter which variable you use. If you were integrating a function of t in example 9, then it would matter what you variable you are integrating against.